# Redis: should I convert IPs into integers?

Tags: ruby, string, caching, integer, redis

I need to store IP addresses in a redis hash.

Will there be considerable memory savings if the IP is stored as an integer instead of a string?

I would be using Ruby's `IPAddr` to convert the IP to an int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how you do it. In Redis keys and (leaf) values are strings. If you would convert an IP address to an int and send it to Redis like the following code you wouldn't save much:

```
redis.hset("xyz", "ip", IPAddr.new(ip).to_i)
```

The IP "255.255.255.255", for example, is 15 bytes in dotted quad form, its integer representation "4294967295" is ten bytes when saved as a string, which is what the code above will do.

To get down to just four bytes stored in Redis you would have to send the raw bytes "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF".

In Ruby you would do it this way:

```
packed_ip = IPAddr.new(ip).hton
redis.hset("xyz", "ip", packed_ip)
```

And then when you read it back

```
packed_ip = redis.hget("xyz", "ip")
ip = IPAddr.ntop(packed_ip)
```

What `IPAddr.hton` and `IPAddr.ntop` do is this:

```
packed_ip = ip.split('.').map(&:to_i).pack('C4') # hton
ip = packed_ip.unpack('C4').join('.') # ntop
```

Then there's the whole thing about IPv6 and whatnot, but I think `IPAddr` has you covered there.

Comment: Thanks Theo for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to reconsider your approach a little as well, with the advent of IPv6 storing as an integer would be a very bad idea if you ever wish to convert your application to use IPv6 (or even just support it).

These days memory/disk space is cheap so you'd be better investing in a workable future proof solution than worry about disk space if you can.

In this case a string would still be the best option since you can then utilize IPv6 and IPv4 in the same field.

Comment: There's no such thing as `VARBINARY` here, Redis isn't MySQL. If you save 4 bytes, it saves 4 bytes, if you throw two gigs at it, it saves two gigs. Also, it's not a matter of disk being cheap or not -- Redis is an in-memory database. Read the docs at http://redis.io

Comment: Apologies :) I've removed the database reference, the point still stands though. IF you want to utilize (and future proof) the application thats using redis then IPv6 is something to consider in which case a string would be the best option since IPv6 cannot be stored in int (it could be stored in 2* big ints). With the double colon notation you could shrink this further.

Comment: You're right that with IPv6 the trade off is less clear. Always using 16 bytes, or hoping that most values will be less than 16 bytes when represented as strings? However, there's no problem storing 16 byte integer numbers in Redis, just pack them the same way and you're good. Redis does not care, in a way you can think of it using `VARBINARY` for everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you store and ip as an integer it will use up 4 bytes. as a string "abc.def.ghi.jkl" it will use up 16 bytes when stored as a null-terminated ascii string, so it is at least a factor of 4 or even 7+ if stored as an unicode string. Also searching for integers is much faster than for strings because your processor is optimized to compare integers...

Comment: The last sentence is not relevant. If the IPs are values there will be no searching, and if they are keys there's no searching either, since it's all hash lookups. Also, just sending `IPAddr.new(ip).to_i` to Redis does not mean that you store just 4 bytes, to do that you need to go a bit further (see my answer).